# What is the difference between conservative and non-conservative confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, descriptive-statistics

I want to answer this question by I can't.

**What is the 95% conservative confidence interval for the population of all teens proportion who get from 6 to 8 hours of sleep per night in average ?**

I want to know the difference between **conservative** and **non conservative** confidence intervals.
How do I answer this type of question?
[image]

I have also uploaded the solution but I want to understand it by equations, and how to reach this answer.
there is also another question which I can't understand about the difference between **confidence interval** and **conservative confidence interval**
[image]

Comment: What does the question text say? What's it a confidence interval for?

Comment: I edited the question please review again thanks

Comment: I added the question above in the post , can you review it and provide an answer? thanks

Comment: What does the formula sheet say?  This concept of "conservative" seems to be little known and might be peculiar to the textbook or professor you are using.

Comment: A procedure is called conservative typically when it provides some assurance that it does not overestimate statistical significance. For example, Wilcoxon signed-rank testing does not require normalcy thus is more conservative than paired *t*-testing. The point here is that we do not know which procedures are being used in the text leading to the questions, thus cannot say for sure what the context is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confidence interval for a proportion requires you to calculate the standard error of the proportion. The standard error depends on the population proportion. Since you don't know the population proportion (which is why you're making a confidence interval in the first place), it's ambiguous how to calculate the standard error to use in the confidence interval.

One solution is to use the sample proportion in the formula for the standard error. The formula for this is the following:

$$CI=\hat p \pm Z\sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1-\hat p)}{n}}$$

where $\hat p$ is the sample proportion, $Z$ is the critical Z-statistic for $\alpha = .05$ for a two-tailed test, and $n$ is the sample size. This is the formula that was used to calculate the bounds for the answer that was marked correct, except that $2$ was used for $Z$ as an approximation to $1.96$, the actual correct value for a 95% confidence interval. Unfortunately, this strategy can lead to confidence intervals that are too narrow. Because this confidence interval has lower than the required coverage (i.e., the true confidence level will be less than 95%), this confidence interval is non-conservative. A conservative confidence interval is a wider one because it excludes fewer potential values of the population parameter.

Another solution is to use the largest standard error possible for this distribution, which is the one that occurs when the population propertion is .5. The largest value that $p(1-p)$ can take is $.25$. If $p$ is anything less than or greater than .5, $p(1-p)$ will be smaller. So, we can replace $\hat p(1-\hat p)$ in the above formula with $.5(1-.5)$. Because this is the largest standard error possible for a distribution of sample proportions, your confidence interval will be too wide when the population proportion is different from .5 and exactly right when the population proportion is equal to .5. This is what makes it conservative. On the other hand, the previous formula that uses $\hat p$ will be systematically too narrow when the population proportion is .5.

---

The values they used in the formula were

$$\frac{460}{1368} \pm 2\sqrt{\frac{\frac{460}{1368}(1-\frac{460}{1368})}{1368}}$$

Comment: Thanks I think this is the right answer. but I didn't get what will be the equation if I want to calculate the conservative confidence interval . can you write the equation the same as you write above? thanks

Comment: Just replace $\hat p$ with .5.

Comment: Thanks Noah, well for the same source I am solving , I noticed that there is a difference between Confidence interval, and conservative confidence interval. So I updated the question again with the second question with a false answer I made, can you explain the difference please because I searched a lot and no resource found helpful. regards

Comment: I get the correct answer (A) for the second question by applying the formula and inserting $.5(1-.5)$ for $\hat p(1 - \hat p)$ because it's the conservative confidence interval. You applied the non-conservative confidence interval formula. Note for some reason in this second question they used 1.96 for $Z$ whereas in the first question they used $2$. This seems like a poorly taught class if they aren't explaining the concepts to you and are changing formulas with no warning.

Answer (score 0):

The term conservative is not meant to describe a 'type' of confidence interval that mathematically operates differently. The term means, exactly what you would expect. If you are using a 95% confidence interval you are being conservative, because you are allowing for a large range with a greater probability your statistic falls in that range. A less conservative confidence interval would have a lower probability, because you are taking a greater risk in the statistic not being within the range.

Comment: thanks for illustration , so could you solve this problem by steps?also what is meant by non conservative?